# Click no botão não faz nada

Tags: java, android

Coloquei um botão na `activity_main` e fiz uma segunda tela. 
A ideia era, ao clicar no botão, carregasse essa outra tela. E na classe `MainActivity.java` coloquei que ao clicar no botão, iria carregar a tela.
Só que, ao clicar no botão, não acontece absolutamente nada.

Alguém aí tem alguma ideia do que pode ser?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button btCadastro;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btCadastro = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btCadastro);
    btCadastro.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            chamaCadastro();

        }
    });
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

}
public void chamaCadastro(){

    setContentView(R.layout.telacadastro);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema nesse caso é que não poderá usar o `setContentView` após ter inicializado a `Activity` no `onCreate`.

Você terá que iniciar uma nova `Activity` com esse layout.
E pode ser feito dessa maneira:

```
public void chamaCadastro(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, CadastroActivity.class);

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Ai sim, nessa `CadastroActivity`, terá o seu layout do `telacadastro`.
Inicializando como:

```
public class CadastroActivityextends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.telacadastro);
    }
}
```

Recomendo essa abordagem, porque você consegue fazer seu aplicativo muito mais modular e com baixo acoplamento e reuso, além de separar as lógicas de cada tela com muito mais facilidade.

Como você citou que era iniciante, recomendo a leitura dos guias do Android, em especial o sobre [Activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html)

Comment: @Walkim Vou dar uma olhada nessa parte da documentação. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 2):

Aparentemente você deseja iniciar uma nova tela (`Activity`). certo?

Para iniciar uma nova tela(`Activity` no android) você tem que fazer assim:

```java
public void chamaCadastro(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CadastroActivity.class);
    this.startActivity(intent);
}
```

No caso você teria que criar a `Activity` `CadastroActivity`.

Recomendo dar uma olhada na documentação do Android, no método [startActivity(Intent intent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29)

Comment: Entendi. Vou criar essa nova Activity e testar. Obrigado!